# Sorry, cannot pickle code objects with closures. Again

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython

I have the following piece of code written in python:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer
from IPython.parallel import Client
dview = Client()[:]
Tracer()();#First Tracer
numeric_rigs = dview.map_sync(lambda b,c=cluster,o=options:calculate_rig(c,b,o),borders);
Tracer()();#Second Tracer
```

When I stop on the first Tracer and manually run the second line in a debugger - everything works fine. However if only I continue running the code after the first Tracer the second line fails with message **Sorry, cannot pickle code objects with closures**.

I don't understand why this line works in debugger but doesn't work on its own. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you importing `cluster`, `options`, `border`, and `calculate_rig` from?  If you include your imports, so people can try your code out, you'll more likely get help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not runnable, as is, but I can guess something that you might try.

Try:

```
dview.use_dill()
```

This will give you better serialization, if you have `dill` installed.

Get `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Or use `pip` to install `dill`.